# Using a function mfile within another function mfile

Tags: matlab

May sound trivial but it is causing me great confusion.

How do I use a function I have defined in a function m-file, within another m-file. For example say I have a function called data and another function called plot_my_way where I have defined a way of using the data and creating a specific plot, how can I use the function 'plot_my_way' within the function data?

Comment: as long as it is in the path it you can just call it. What's your actual error?

Comment: Undefined function 'plot_my_way' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @user3190506 It means MATLAB can't find your function, which suggests you haven't put it on your MATLAB path. Either put both functions in the same directory or put them on your MATLAB path.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know what the following error mean Undefined function 'colon' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d real'.

Answer (score 1):

a function file can be called directly as **plot_my_way();** in the function m-file data. Just make sure that both the files should be in same directory and name of function is same as that of m-file name.

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be in the same directory, but on the MATLAB path.